# const modifiers In ANSI C and ANSI C++

Tags: c++, c, ansi-c

Is this true ?

1.if we use the const modifier alone , it defaults to int. For example,

```
const size = 10;
```

means

```
const int size =10;
```

2.ANSI C does not require an initializer to const;if none is given, it initializes the const to 0. For Example,

```
const int i;
```

means

```
const i = 0;
```

please give ans. according to ANSI std

Comment: you taking a test or something?

Comment: What happened to `=` in `const size 10`? Your question seems to be about the missing `int`. Why did you remove `=` as well?

Answer (score 3):

1. This is true for C89/90. This is not true for C99 or C++. The "implicit int" rule was outlawed in C99 and never existed in C++.

   However,

   ```
   const size 10;
   ```

   is not valid C syntax. The `=` is still required. A very ancient pre-standard version of C  (called CRM C) used initialization syntax without `=`, but that version of the language didn't even have `const` in it yet.
2. Not true. In C and objects with *static storage duration* are zero-initailized by default. This means, for example, that any *file-scope* object is zero-initialized by default, regardless of whether it is `const` or not. Local variables are not zero-initialized by default, regardless of whether they are `const` or not. In other words, this issue is completely unrelated to `const`.

   C++ implements similar specification. All objects with *static storage duration* are zero-initialized before any other initialization take place.

Answer (score 1):

According to the standard (C99, I haven't checked C++ or earlier C versions), neither of these is true.

1. If you look at the grammar definition for declarations (section 6.7), you will find that the type specifier is not optional.
2. On default initialisation (section 6.7.8), we find the following:

   > If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
   >   explicitly, its value is indeterminate. If an object that has static
   >   storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:
   >
   > ...
   >
   > - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
   >
   > ...

   Nothing about `const` here.

Comment: In C++ this code doesn't compile too.

Answer (score 1):

http://ideone.com/kl9CZ No, it is not true.

C allowed default `int`, but only until 1999, at which point they made it illegal.  A long time ago, variables defaulted to `int` in MSVC 2003's C++, but in standard C++, that has been illegal since the language was standardized.  In fact, when I type your code into recent versions of MSVC, I get the error message:

> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

To my knowledge, leaving out the `=` was never legal in C or C++.

There are *some* cases where C and C++ will zero initialize variables to zero, but they are cases where you have something along the lines of `int a = int();`, and globals/statics are zero-initialized.  In your code, (if they're in a function) neither C nor C++ will zero initialize those variables.